# Debian unable to find bootable device

Tags: ubuntu, boot, parrotsec

I am trying to install Linux Mint (ubuntu based) and Parrot OS (Debian based) on two separate SSDs. Mint works great I have installed it and it booted with no problem. Afterwards, I switched internal SSD to the other one and I installed Parrot on this one. It also worked great and I could boot afterwards.

But here comes the problem. When I switch SSD again to Mint it works and boots without a problem but when I switch it back to Parrot it prints Bootable device not found. My TPM is disabled, I have also disabled fastboot and secure boot but I still think that this is something with my bios. My notebook is Fujitsu LifeBook e556 which don't have an option to add trusted HDDs (I have seen Acers with this option which simply allows you to add more disks to secure boot).

Any ideas on how to fix this so I could have 2 separate interchangeable SSDs with two different systems?

UPDATE: Yesterday I have tried installing Linux Mint also on the other SSD and it works flawlesly so the problem won't be in my BIOS but probably in Parrot (and Kali) itself. Maybe there should be a different grub config.

Comment: So, you switch between SSDs, and each one has it's own MBR/Bootloader setup right? I had a simmilar issue(but not disk related) with an ASUS motherboard, that i have not only to turn off the computer, but to pull out the POWER CORD from it's back, removing any source of energy. After some reboots, the motherboard entered in some sort of "vegetative" state where it would not map usb ports and built-in ethernet... and the only way to fix it was removing the energy and not only powering off

Comment: yes you are right. So you think I should remove battery from notebook, wait a few seconds and then try it again?

Comment: I would give it a try :)

Comment: I tried it but it didnt help

Comment: Bios or Uefi/Efi mode?

Comment: Uefi mode both SSDs